# SQL Search Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently working on a query to search a specific table.  The requirements say that I need to grab all records where any of a group of fields are `like` the input value.  As such I have a query that looks similar to

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE Col1 like @input
    or Col2 like @input
    or Col3 like @input
```

There could be any number of columns in the where clause.  One particular customer is going to have 50 columns. As such, this where clause is going to get fairly expensive.

Is there another syntax or method that can be used so that I could say "does the input value exist in any of x columns?"

Would you write the query differently?

Comment: What database platform are you using? MS SQL Server, MySql, something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on which and where wildcards are allowed these queries could be expensive indeed, because the optimizer will have trouble using indexes on many of them to speed them up.

If you are running this on MS SQL Server you might consider using the Fulltext searching features and the CONTAINS keyword to implement this.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE CONTAINS
((col1,col2,col3) ,@input)
```

Or to search all text-indexed columns

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE CONTAINS
(* ,@input)
```

Comment: Fulltext searching is something I still don't quite get. It would *still* require him to use `contains` on those 50 columns wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, but you could use a more compact syntax. Honestly your bigger issue is going to be performance, not adding the columns to the query. If you are going to be searching on open ended wildcards (*term*) I think Fulltext will perform better because of the way the data is indexed.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142547.aspx for the overview of fulltext search features. If all the columns the OP might use are fulltext indexed, it can search all of them. However, insert performance can be heavily impacted.

Comment: Not quite the same syntax - there are many features that will help reduce the expense of a freetext search. +1

Comment: I didn't know the CONTAINS(*, @input) syntax. That definitly is a viable solution. +1.

Answer (score 1):

I'd structure the data differently. Are the types of these 50 columns all going to be the same? Since you're using "like", I'm going to assume they are all varchar columns. Why not have 3 tables, 'MyTable', a table with the string data (whatever it may be), and a join table with references to both.

At this point, your query becomes:

```
select mt.*
from MyTable mt
    inner join JoinTable jt
        on jt.MyTableId = mt.Id
    inner join DataTable dt
        on dt.Id = jt.DataTableId
where dt.Data like @Input
```

Obviously, on SO, we see a lot of answers that are simply, "Your data is structured wrong. Redo it." This is not always the most helpful. If for some reason (bureaucracy around database structure, legacy dependencies on this structure, etc.) you cannot restructure it, you need to realize you're pivoting these columns. At this point you'll need to look at options for pivoting this, which will vary based on how analytical/transactional (read/write heavy) this db is. If you are very read heavy, you might be ok duplicating the data into a pivot table that you update each time you update 'MyTable'. If you're more transactional, a function or view will at least abstract this pivoted structure but the query will be expensive. MS SQL full text search capabilities would work similarly to duplicating the data and updating on inserts and depending on the nature of your "like" queries, may read faster.

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't need live data**, you can opt for a data-warehouse scenario.

- every day, drop and reload a table containing only an ID and VALUE column
- use a SELECT INTO like

> ```
>    SELECT ID, Col1 FROM MyTable  
>    UNION ALL SELECT ID, Col2 FROM MyTable  
>    UNION ALL SELECT ID, Col3 FROM MyTable
> ```

- Index the table from front to back, left to right, ...

This allows you to simplify your original select and keep performance on par

```
SELECT mt.*
FROM   MyTable mt
       INNER JOIN MyDWTable mdwt ON mdwt.ID = mt.ID
WHERE  mdwt.Value LIKE @Input
```